# Coded UI test builder record and playback functionality fails for Backbone SPA

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I was analyzing Coded UI record and playback for sample Backbone single page application.

Steps followed:

1, Record steps.

2, Created a test method and added recorded steps method in it.

3, Ran test and received error\exception element not found.

what I observed that in UIMap class, Coded UI creates all html elements at the beginning and beign a dynamic nature of backbone single page application, some controls won't be available at web page load and will appear on DOM after some events. e.g. on button click -> user gets menu. Coded UI initially tries to fetch this menu in my case which would not be available in beginning and fails.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with SPA. Have you solved it?